# Is blu-ray writing support reliable yet?

Tags: blu-ray

Blu-ray writers have reduced in price a lot recently, but there are few success stories on the web about writing blu-ray disks using Ubuntu (and the same goes for GNU/Linux in general).

Are any of the new low-cost blu-ray writers supported?  Can anybody confirm that they've personally used them with success?  What software did you use (I'm most interested in tools that operate at the hardware/protocol level, such as growisofs, rather than the GUI tools that wrap them)?

Comment: I've had bad experiences with cheap BD-RW disks (7 months of use and then unreadable), but that had everything to do with the media and not the OS or the drive and drivers.

Comment: So, you were able to write a blu-ray disk?  Also, you were able to do that reliably, once you found suitable disks?  What hardware (what blu-ray writer) did you use, and what software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've so far found blu-ray writing using growisofs to Verbatim BD-R disks using an LG BH10LS30 blu-ray writer to be reliable.  I've only burned a small handful of disks so far, though.

Answer (score 2):

A new software seems to have a GUI for Bluray disc. It's [Silicon Empire](http://getsilicon.org/). You can install it in Ubuntu by downloading the package in the Downloads section, on the website.

Answer (score 1):

According to the cdrkit homepage, cdrecord has had Blu-Ray support since 2007. The homepages also states that all SCSI-3/mmc compliant drives and all ATAPI/mmc compliant drives are supported. I don't think there is a software issue. You should just look for a burner with good reviews.

Answer (score 1):

It is supported. Just needs some set up. See here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CdDvd/Burning#Blu-Ray_Burning

Answer (score 0):

[According to the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CdDvd/Burning#Burning%20Files%20to%20CD%20or%20DVD), it is possible, however, I have not tried myself.

It says "The only available GUI in [NeroLINUX](http://freshmeat.net/projects/nerolinux). See Burning a DVD or Blu-Ray Disc below for command line instructions."

For playback, there is a post for that as [well on the Ubuntu Wiki.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/BluRayAndHDDVD)

Answer (score 0):

My blu-ray writer works just fine on ubuntu with neroLinux. I have only written one disk but that is limited only by my lack of need for another blu-ray disk , it's not like i tried more that failed. (to be honest , i didn't even need to write the first one either - I just wanted to test my new notebook's blu-ray writer )

Since i use a notebook though (Lifebook NH570 by Fujitsu) I can't give you an idea for a blu-ray writer so that you can buy one - unless you care about the model of the writer included in my notebook.